# Klein Bottle as the connected sum of two projective planes

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces, klein-bottle

Can someone explain intuitively why the Klein bottle is diffeomorphic to the connected sum of two projective planes? I can do this using origamis/fundamental graphs )w/e they are called. is it possible to do it with another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a preferred way to explain this which involves the visualization of Klein bottle and its decomposition into two mobius strips (note that a projective plane minus a disk is a mobius band, hence the equivalence) as rectangles with certain sides identified.

You can find [here](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~muenz/560/Mobius%20Strips%20and%20Klein%20Bottles.pdf) two illustrations, the latter being the one I mentioned above. Actually the whole document is about answering your question in detail.